# Unable to define the correct SQL query to achieve the explained result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help writing a SQL query for the below need. I have spend the last 4 days trying to construct a query, but just not hitting it.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

I have data in table like the attached image.

What I want is to identify those rows which if grouped

- Starting with Country-State-Country-Zip level and
- Moving up like Country-State-Country , Country-State and finally the top level * Country still have a count which is less than 3 rows.

So House_Number 0001,0002,0003,0004 will fall under

```
 US-CA-A-B group ( count = 4)
```

House_Number  0005,0006,0007 will fall under

```
  US-CA-A group ( count = 3)
```

House_Number  0009,0010,0011 will fall under

```
 DE-QW-Q-Y group (count = 3)
```

House_Number  0013,0014,0015 will fall under

```
 AU group (count = 3)
```

So the two rows that I want to select are for House_Number 0008 and 0012

[image: Table Data]

Comment: Why wouldn't DE/QW/Q/X be combined with the three rows before it?

Comment: Maybe I could not explain properly. I will change the color coverage on the DE---Y rows to explain the need . You can only use to club rows together under one higher grouping level if they don't have sufficent rows to satisfy the count of 3 or more at a lower level.                                                              If you observe DE-QW-Q-Y group has enough rows to satisfy count of 3 , so cannt be considered for the DE-QW-Q level .

Comment: By the way, this is a really good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH Step1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TheTable t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT Country, State, County, Zip FROM dbo.TheTable 
            GROUP BY Country, State, County, Zip HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
        ) x1 WHERE t1.Country=x1.Country AND t1.State=x1.State AND t1.County=x1.County AND t1.Zip=x1.Zip
    )
), Step2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM Step1 t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT Country, State, County FROM Step1 
            GROUP BY Country, State, County HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
        ) x2 WHERE t2.Country=x2.Country AND t2.State=x2.State AND t2.County=x2.County
    )
), Step3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM Step2 t3
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT Country, State FROM Step2 
            GROUP BY Country, State HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
        ) x3 WHERE t3.Country=x3.Country AND t3.State=x3.State
    )
), Step4 AS (
    SELECT * FROM Step3 t4
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT Country FROM Step3
            GROUP BY Country HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
        ) x4 WHERE t4.Country=x4.Country
    )
) 
SELECT * FROM Step4
```

Comment: Thanks @razvan-socol , your query gave the desired result .

Comment: But I could run it in SQLite , When I adapted it to my original table in SQL server , it is giving syntax error. maybe some rules are breaking in terms of common table expression definition in SQL Server.

Comment: It should work in SQLite too. I just removed the `dbo` schema before the table name: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/07600/1

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2)

Comment: Add a semicolon (;) before the WITH keyword.

Comment: Thank a lot @razvan-socol. It was a missing parenthesis which was causing the syntax error. My bad. It is working as expected. I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want countries that occur 2 or fewer times. Based on your rule, I don't see why the additional "DE" row wouldn't be combine with the previous three rows.

So:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by country) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt <= 2;
```

EDIT:

For the increased understanding provided by the comment (which is consistent with the question but really clarifies it), you can use a series of `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.country = t.county and
                        t2.state = t.state and
                        t2.county = t.county and
                        t2.zip = t.zip
                  group by t2.country, t2.state, t2.county, t2.zip
                  having count(*) > 2
                 ) and
       not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.country = t.county and
                        t2.state = t.state and
                        t2.county = t.county 
                  group by t2.country, t2.state, t2.county
                  having count(*) > 2
                 ) and
       not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.country = t.county and
                        t2.state = t.state
                  group by t2.country, t2.state
                  having count(*) > 2
                 ) and
       not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.country = t.county
                  group by t2.country
                  having count(*) > 2
                 );
```

EDIT 2:

This is a tricky problem.  Let me assume you have an id on each row that defines them uniquely.  Then:

```
with t1 as (
      select id
      from t
      except
      select id
      from t 
      group by country, state, county, zip
      having count(*) > 2
     ),
     t2 as (
      select id
      from t1
      except
      select id
      from t1
      group by country, state, county
      having count(*) > 2
     ),
     t3 as (
      select id
      from t2
      except
      select id
      from t2
      group by country, state
      having count(*) > 2
     ),
     t4 as (
      select id
      from t3
      except
      select id
      from t3
      group by country, state, county, zip
      having count(*) > 2
     )
select *
from t4;
```

If you don't have a unique id, you can try concatenating all the columns together to generate one -- or use `row_number()` with a stable sort.

If you want other columns, then join them back in at the final stage.

Comment: Hi Gordon , I tried your query. This is not giving the House Number 0012 row. Only giving one row back , i.e house number 0008

Comment: Hi Gordon your updated query seems to have syntactical flaw.  The query is trying to select a column which is not part of the group by clause .  Like this part -> select id
      from t 
      group by country, state, county, zip                                                        this doesn't work.